# Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The Content-Type header cannot be set to a multipart type for this request."

Tags: powershell, scripting, sftp

I am working with a script that is supposed to first check if a PC is alive then FTP a file to a server. However, when running the script I am getting the following error:

Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The Content-Type header cannot be set to a multipart type for this request."

Here is the script:

```
$down = "C:\Script\log\down-hosts.log"
$computers = Get-Content "C:\Script\list\Computers.txt"

$sourcefileName = "source_file.csv"

#ftp server 
$ftp = "sftp://servername" 
$user = "user" 
$pass = "pass"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)

# Create empty log file for down hosts (overwrite if exists)
New-Item $down -type file -force

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
if ( Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ) {
  Write-Host "$computer is up"
  Write-Host "Uploading \\$computer\c$\UPS CSV Exports\$sourcefile..."
  $sourcefilePath = "\\$computer\c$\UPS CSV Exports"
  $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$computer+"_"+$sourcefileName)
  $webclient.UploadFile($uri,$sourcefilePath+"/"+$sourcefileName)
  if($? -eq $True) {
  write-host "$ftp$sourcefileName ok"
  Remove-Item $sourcefilePath"\"$sourcefileName
 }
} else {
  Write-Host "$computer is down"
  "$computer is down" | Out-File $down -append 
  }
}
```

The idea is that the script finds the file, then uploads to the FTP server. If the PC is not available, it writes to a log file so I know to manually retrieve the file.

Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, if the FTP part is killing this, it is also possible to just copy/paste or move the file to a network path since the FTP server is on the same network.

Comment: For one, I'm pretty sure the .NET WebClient class doesn't support SFTP connections. I'm thinking that might be the source of the problem, despite a non-helpful error message.

Comment: SFTP is FTP over SSH - Windows does not natively support SSH in any way. Perhaps you mean FTPS (FTP over SSL/TLS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-wrote the script a bit and got it working without using the FTP protocol. I changed it to use the move command instead:

```
$down = "C:\Script\log\down-hosts.log"
$computers = Get-Content "C:\Script\list\Computers.txt"
$TargetPath = "\\ServerName\ShareName\Path"
$SourceFileName = "source_file.csv"
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
  if ( Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
{
    $sourcefilePath = "\\$computer\c$\UPS CSV Exports\$SourceFileName"
    Write-Host "$computer is up"
    Write-Host "Copying $SourceFilePath ..."
    Try {
      If (Test-Path $SourceFilePath) {
         Move-Item $SourceFilePath "$TargetPath\$computer`_$SourceFileName" -force
      } Else {
         Throw "$SourceFilePath does not exist"
      }
    } Catch {
       Write-Host "Error: $($Error[0].Exception.Message)"
    }
  } Else {
    Write-Host "$computer is down"
    "$computer is down" | Out-File $down -append 
  }
}
```

After making the changes, the script works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a misleading error since it is probably trying to execute a POST request on the sftp backend you have specified.

> The UploadFile method sends a local file to a resource. This method
>   uses the STOR command to upload an FTP resource. For an HTTP resource,
>   the POST method is used.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: if I were to adjust this to instead of FTP the file, copy/move the file, what would the syntax be? Thank you!